# Do I have to execute the NSDecimalCompact() function on every NSDecimal I create?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

The documentation confuses me about this. They say:

```
void NSDecimalCompact (
   NSDecimal *number
);
```

> Discussion Formats number so that
>   calculations using it will take up as
>   little memory as possible. All the
>   NSDecimal... arithmetic functions
>   expect compact NSDecimal arguments.

The last part is important:

> All the
>   NSDecimal... arithmetic functions
>   expect compact NSDecimal arguments.

So that means, that I have to execute NSDecimalCompact() on every NSDecimal, every time I provide it as a parameter to one of the NSDecimal... arithmetic functions? Or would I do that only once when creating the NSDecimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to call `NSDecimalCompact()`, the results from `NSDecimal..()` functions are compact as long as the return value is `NSCalculationNoError`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? How do I know which situations/functions yield non-compact decimals?